# Вопрос с TabBarController

Tags: swift, controller

Всем привет! У меня есть TabBarController, который имеет 2 таба. И я хочу, чтобы изначально показывался он, но на экране был активный другой, третий контроллер, но он не должен входить в видимый снизу TabBarItem. Возможно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Просто накройте при старте приложения экран (кроме области табов) элементом Container View и покажите ваш третий контролер.

Comment: хмммм...Звучит интересно. Попробую реализовать. Никогда так не делал. Если что - отпишусь)